# Running one python script within another script using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a script to walk over a directory, and convert all the python2 files to python3.
There is a utitliy (2to3.py) to acheive that. ( I am using python2.7 interpreter)

I have the following code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import pathlib

APP_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/XXXX/Test/'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(APP_FOLDER):
    for inputFile in filenames:
        if pathlib.Path(inputFile).suffix == ".py":
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, inputFile)
            with open(file_path) as f:
                num_lines = len(f.readlines())
            print dirpath
            print inputFile
            print "lines of code: ", num_lines
            print "converting to python 3"
            cmd ="py C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\\2to3.py "+inputFile+" -w"
            p1=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
            p1.wait()
            if p1.returncode ==0:
                print "Success"
            else:
                print "failure"
```

At the path mentioned, I have a subdirectory named "FolderA" and within that there is a simple python file having the syntax of python2 and a division operation.

I receive an error as below:

```
C:/Users/XXXX/Test/FolderA
Sample.py
lines of code:  7
converting to python 3
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Can't open Sample.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Sample.py'
RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
RefactoringTool: Can't open Sample.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Sample.py'
failure
-------------------*************--------------------
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try replacing `cmd ="py C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\\2to3.py "+inputFile+" -w"` with `cmd ="py C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\\2to3.py "+file_path+" -w"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using, `cmd ="py C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\\2to3.py "+file_path+" -w"`

Answer (score 2):

try change it to this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import pathlib

APP_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/XXXX/Test/'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(APP_FOLDER):
    for inputFile in filenames:
        if pathlib.Path(inputFile).suffix == ".py":
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, inputFile)
            with open(file_path) as f:
                num_lines = len(f.readlines())
            print dirpath
            print inputFile
            print "lines of code: ", num_lines
            print "converting to python 3"
            cmd = "py C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\\2to3.py "+file_path+" -w"
            p1=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
            p1.wait()
            if p1.returncode ==0:
                print "Success"
            else:
                print "failure"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `dirpath` with `inputFile` for the command as well. For your case, replace `inputFile` with `file_path` should fix the error since you already have `file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, inputFile)` defined in the code.

Also there're these issues in the code that may cause error in certain cases:

1. some `\` characters in your `cmd` are not escaped. To fix this you may use the raw string literals syntax, like `r'''path\no\need\to\escape'''`;
2. You really should use the `list` input format for the `Popen` function, otherwise the command would fail if your file path contains spaces. `Popen(['/path/to/py', 'arg1', 'arg2' ...])`

Comment: Thank you @ZigZagT for the insights, Incorporating the same in my code.